# How can I get all leaf nodes of a tree?

Tags: java

Suppose I have a node in a tree, how can I get all leaf nodes whose ancestor is this node?

I have defined the TreeNode like this:

```
public class TreeNode<T>
{
    /** all children of the node */
    private List<TreeNode<T>> children = new ArrayList<TreeNode<T>>();
    /** the parent of the node, if the node is root, parent = null */
    private TreeNode<T> parent = null;
    /** the stored data of the node */
    private T data = null;

    /** the method I want to implement */
    public Set<TreeNode<T>> getAllLeafNodes()
    {
        Set<TreeNode<T>> leafNodes = new HashSet<TreeNode<T>>();
        return leafNodes;
    }
}
```

Comment: Keep traversing childrens and all those children who have empty children list are leave? What's the issue?

Comment: A leaf node should have en empty list of children; so you can implement a method isLeaf() on your node. And then you will have to recursively check for all children of your node.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use recursion.

- if the node itself is a leaf, return it
- otherwise, return all the leaf-nodes of its children

Something like this (not tested):

```
public Set<TreeNode<T>> getAllLeafNodes() {
    Set<TreeNode<T>> leafNodes = new HashSet<TreeNode<T>>();
    if (this.children.isEmpty()) {
        leafNodes.add(this);
    } else {
        for (TreeNode<T> child : this.children) {
            leafNodes.addAll(child.getAllLeafNodes());
        }
    }
    return leafNodes;
}
```

Comment: I wanted to check in internet if my method for gettin all leaves is fine and I've found this anwser that looks exactly like mine, except I have used List instead of Set. I assume that this is ok then :D

Answer (score 0):

Create a stack and push root node.

```
Stack<Node> st = new Stack<>();
st.push(root);      
CL(st.peek());
```

Call the recursive method.

```
public void CL(Node root){
        if (st.peek().left == null && st.peek().right == null ) {//if leaf node
            System.out.println(st.peek().data);//print
            st.pop();
            return;
        }
        else{
            if(st.peek().left != null){
                st.add(st.peek().left);
                CL(st.peek());
            }
            if(st.peek().right != null){
                st.add(st.peek().right);
                CL(st.peek());
            }
        }
        st.pop();
    }
```